# How to convert a list<String> to string with prefix and postfix in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I convert a list of numbers to a string which could be used in JSON, with Kotlin in Android?

I used this could but this doesn't work:

```
l.toTypedArray().contentDeepToString()
```

input:

```
l: List<String> =[102,103]
```

output:

```
s:String = "["102","103"]"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `joinToString` like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var l: List<String> = listOf("102" ,"103")
    return this.joinToString(prefix = "[\"", postfix = "\"]", separator = "\",\"")
}
```

The output looks like the desired one:

```
["102","103"]
```

For more information, read [the documentation of `joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html).

You have the possibility of making this an extension function of `List<String>` in order to reduce code redundancy, if you need it more than once in your code:

```
// extend List<String> by a new method that creates your quoted String from the items
fun List<String>.toQuotedString(): String {
    return this.joinToString(prefix = "[\"", postfix = "\"]", separator = "\",\"")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var l: List<String> = listOf("102" ,"103")
    println(l.toQuotedString())  // you can just use this method in your code
}
```

**Addition**
If you want it for a list of *real* numbers (your and my examples are using a `List<String>`), you can just do the same for a `List<Int>`:

```
fun List<Int>.toQuotedString(): String {
    return this.joinToString(prefix = "[\"", postfix = "\"]", separator = "\",\"")
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there anyway that I could convert this list to another list like ["102", "103"] ?

Comment: @MaryJane Do you mean converting a `List<Int>` to a `List<String>`?

Comment: No, my list is already list of strings. but If I want to send this through a json it needs to be like : `"key" : ["1023", "1024"]` in a Query map

Comment: @MaryJane I don't really get what you are trying to achieve... Can't you just put a `"\"key\"" : + l.toQuotedString()`?